Progress bar doesn't progress for a pattern involves Alternatives (|) and Condition (/;)
This is a follow-up question to this one. (I hope it is ok to post a separate question. )
I have a large list like this one
largelist = RandomSample[Range[3000000], 50000];

Now I want to use Cases to match all elements in this list by another list
matchlist = RandomSample[Range[1000000], 10000];

This could take some time so I want to add a progress indicator. @xzczd provided a solution in the question linked above:
i = 0; newlist = Monitor[Cases[largelist, 
  _?(i++; MemberQ[matchlist, #] &)], 
    ProgressIndicator[i, {0, Length@largelist}]]

However, @xzczd also suggested to use Alternatives instead of MemberQ which is much faster for large lists. However, I cannot implement the progress bar in this case:
i = 0; newlist3 = Monitor[Cases[largelist, 
  Alternatives @@ matchlist /; (i++; True)], 
    Column@{DateString[], Refresh[Pause[0.03]; 
      ProgressIndicator[i, {0, Length@largelist}]]}]

does not work, the progress bar does not "progress" - it remains an empty bar...

This just looks like the goal to slow down the Cases

I'm with a mobile so cannot test at the moment, but what do you mean by "does not work"? Please be more specific.

@JasonB. what do you mean by that? That Monitorslows down the peformance of the code above?

@M.A. - I mean that the pattern matcher is fast, and Cases is fast when it is just using the pattern matcher. When you make a pattern with _? then it has to use the evaluator instead of the pattern matcher - it has to call top-level code instead of staying in the compiled C-code underlying Cases.  On top of that, having the function increment a counter and then monitoring the progress means kernel->front end communication at every step.

@JasonB. But still for very large lists it could be a benefit to monitor the progress - even at the cost of slowing down the process..

The question is about finding the elements of largelist that are in matchlist including duplicates & keeping original order, while having progress reporting. This isn't too difficult:
Pick[largelist,
    ResourceFunction["DynamicMap"][MatchQ[Alternatives @@ matchlist], largelist]
]


I'd suggest breaking the task down to smaller chunks rather than come up with a function that monitors every single step. For example:
With[
  {step = 100},
  Monitor[
    Catenate[
      Table[
        Cases[Take[largelist, {i, UpTo[i + step - 1]}],  Alternatives @@ matchlist], 
        {i, 1, Length@largelist, step}]], 
    ProgressIndicator[i, {0, Length@largelist}]]]

You could also Partition your largelist first and make your own function to do the Cases and manage the iterator.
i = 0;
With[
  {partlist = Partition[largelist, UpTo[100]]},
  Monitor[
    Catenate[(i++; Cases[#, Alternatives @@ matchlist]) & /@ partlist], 
    ProgressIndicator[i, {0, Length@partlist}]]]

Caveat: I didn't do much testing of these, and my step size was arbitrary. Double check the iterator math take care with edge cases.

Well, this becomes obvious once one notices it, but I myself never noticed this before, and fail to find a duplicate, so let me elaborate a bit. First of all:

...the progress bar does not "progress" - it remains an empty bar...

This isn't quite correct:
SeedRandom[123];
largelist = RandomSample[Range[3000000], 50000];
matchlist = RandomSample[Range[1000000], 10000];
i = 0; newlist3 = 
 Monitor[Cases[largelist, Alternatives @@ matchlist /; (i++; True)], 
  Column@{DateString[], 
    Refresh[Pause[0.03]; 
     ProgressIndicator[i, {0, Length@largelist}]]}];


What's more interesting is:
i
(* 160 *)

Length@newlist3
(* 160 *)

Why does this happen? This is because, just like And (&&) or Or (||), short-circuit evaluation also happens in the matching process of patterns involving Condition (/;) and PatternTest (?), and the evaluation order is (naturally) from left to right. Minimal example:
i = 123; MatchQ[2, 2 /; (i++; True)]; i
(* 124 *)

i = 123; MatchQ[1, 2 /; (i++; True)]; i
(* 123 *)

i = 123; MatchQ[2, 2?((i++; True) &)]; i
(* 124 *)

i = 123; MatchQ[1, 2?((i++; True) &)]; i
(* 123 *)

Notice that 2 /; (i++; True) is the shorthand for Condition[2, i++; True], and 2?((i++; True) &) is the shorthand for PatternTest[2, (i++; True) & ]. In other words, 2nd argument of Condition/PatternTest will come into play only if the pattern in 1st argument matches. This will definitely make the progress bar inaccurate.
"OK, then how to fix?" A possible fix would be
i = 0; With[{patt = Alternatives @@ matchlist}, 
  newlist3 = 
   Monitor[Cases[largelist, a_ /; (i++; MatchQ[a, patt])], 
    ProgressIndicator[i, {0, Length@largelist}]]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {2.8451, Null} *)

For comparison:
i = 0; newlist = 
  Monitor[Cases[largelist, _?(i++; MemberQ[matchlist, #] &)], 
   ProgressIndicator[i, {0, Length@largelist}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {16.0446, Null} *)

However, as pointed by Jason in comment above, the best solution is probably forgetting about monitoring:
newlist3 = 
  Cases[largelist, Alternatives @@ matchlist]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.0058649, Null} *)

